# Save large amount of numpy arrays in single file and use it to fit keras model

Tags: numpy, machine-learning, keras, hdf5, numpy-ndarray

I have huge amount of numpy arrays that do not fit in RAM. Lets say millions of:

```
np.arange(10)
```

1. I want to save them on the file system in a single file, chunk by chunk.
2. I want to read them from the file and feed them to my keras model using `model.fit_generator`

I read about [dask](https://dask.org/) which works with large data that does not fit in memory but could not manage to achieve my goals.

Comment: All the same size, or differing?

Comment: Have you considered HDF5 file, with h5py or pytables module?

Comment: @hpaulj all numpy arrays represent images 224x224x3 so their size should be the same
@ kcw78, I first considered using numpy.savez_compressed, but saw it does not have append method - I plan to put all the arrays in the same file. I am now looking at hdf5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write your files to Disk with pickle:

```
pickle.dump((x, y), open(file, "wb"), protocol=pickle.HIGHEST_PROTOCOL)
```

Then create a list of test and train files and create a generator:

```
def raw_generator(files):
    while 1:      
        for file_num, file in enumerate(files):
            try:
                x, y = pickle.load(open(file, 'rb'))                   
                batches = int(np.ceil(len(y) / batch_size))
                for i in range(0, batches):                        
                    end = min(len(x), i * batch_size + batch_size)
                    yield x[i * batch_size:end], y[i * batch_size:end]

            except EOFError:
                print("error" + file)

train_gen = preprocessing.generator(training_files)
test_gen = preprocessing.generator(test_files)
```

Finally call fit_generator:

```
history = model.fit_generator(
                generator=train_gen,
                steps_per_epoch= (len(training_files)*data_per_file)/batch_size,
                epochs=epochs
                validation_data=test_gen,
                validation_steps=(len(test_files)*data_per_file)/batch_size,        
                use_multiprocessing=False,
                max_queue_size=10,
                workers=1,
                verbose=1)
```

Comment: You can use what ever serlialization you want, it does not really change how to do it. Pickle is fast enough imho

Comment: I deleted my comment, sorry, did not noticed your answer. My question was "is pickle fast enough" and above is @ixeption's answer

Comment: Please accept answers, if you think the answer is correct